# Jsonata create list with concatenated values

Tags: jsonata

I have a list with a structure like this in JSON:

```
{
  "object":{
    "name": "ResultVALUE:"
},
  "list": [
  {
    "result": "Result A"
  },
  {
    "result": "Result B"
  },
  {
    "result": "Result C"
  }
]
}
```

Using the JSONata query language I want to transform the list to this:

```
[
"ResultVALUE: Result A",
"ResultVALUE: Result B",
"ResultVALUE: Result C"
]
```

But I haven't been able to figure out the query for this, I either get the entire list (Result a, Result B, Result C) without the ResultVALUE or the resultVALUE is in a separate object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can build the desired array of objects by using the [map operator](https://docs.jsonata.org/path-operators#-map) on the `list` and taking keys from the root and values from the local context:

```
list.{ $$.object.name: $.result }
```

See it on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/op4gcci

If you need to also trim the `:` at the end of your `ResultVALUE:`, you can do it with the help of [$substringBefore function](https://docs.jsonata.org/string-functions#substringbefore):

```
list.{
  $substringBefore($$.object.name, ":"): $.result
}
```

Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/fCyhAb7

Answer (score 0):

Map the list items concatenating the `object.name` to each of the `result` values.

```
list.(%.object.name & " " & result)
```